# Is my PowerShell execution environment subtly corrupted?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I don't expect an answer, but I'm hoping for a direction.

Sometimes, PowerShell ISE seems to just act, well, weird. The weirdness seems to come out of nowhere. I haven't found a way to reproduce the behavior.

Three days ago, I was writing code that operated on the CERT:\ drive, and Intellisense showed me the parameters for the filesystem provider (`-File` and `-Directory`) instead of the certificate provider (`-ExpiringInDays`).

Today, this code raised an exception.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName OneServer -Credential $admin `
    -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:\ -Recurse -ExpiringInDays 366}
```

```
The system cannot open the device or file specified
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : oneserver
```

Running this snippet of it on my local machine in the same PowerShell session raised the same exception.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:\ -Recurse -ExpiringInDays 366
```

Same exception for `CERT:`, `CERT:\`, and `CERT:\*`.

If I went one directory deeper, using `-Path CERT:\LocalMachine`, it ran without raising an exception, but it returned certificates that expire several years (more than 366 days) from now.

I switched to a different PowerShell session, pasted in both those snippets, and both ran fine. The variable `$admin` is set correctly in both sessions. To me, this seems to point at something going wrong in the execution environment. But just above, Invoke-Command and a local command raised the same error. I don't understand that.

The PowerShell event logs (under Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/Operational) don't show an error for that exception, but they do show an "Access is denied" error related to Invoke-Command.

```
WSMan reported an error with error code: 5. 
 Error message: Connecting to remote server oneserver failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
```

I think this is related to the execution environment. Running identical code in a different PowerShell session worked fine.

**Other things that might be relevant**

- I shutdown, logout, or restart only when Windows forces me to.
- I usually have more than one PowerShell ISE window open. They might stay open for days. During that time, they appear to work fine. (But, would I really know?)
- Sometimes, code with no variables will fail or produce strange output in one window, but will work as expected in another. I don't always notice that the output is strange. (PowerShell tells me that no certificates will expire before 2020. Is that right, or is it strange? I don't always know.)
- Weird IntelliSense behavior (above).
- Pester unit tests run against all my production code every time I open the ISE. Once in a great while, a bunch of them will fail. If I run them again manually, they succeed. Open a new ISE window, and they succeed.

How do I isolate this kind of problem?

```
PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      5.1.15063.413                                                                                                                                                                                       
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                             
BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.413                                                                                                                                                                                      
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.
```

Remote servers are similar: automated jobs run Invoke-Command scripts against all our production servers every day without error. Probably. Maybe.

Comment: What are the results when running Powershell as an administrator? Are your client and the remote machine in the same domain? Thinking of a possible Kerberos double hop issue.

Comment: @root: I usually don't run PowerShell as administrator, so I don't have an answer. Client and all servers are in the same domain. Good thought about a double-hop issue, but that's not happening here. Very similar code runs against all our servers every day without error. (I guess.)

Comment: Start with `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow` and if no results continue to reinstalling PowerShell.

Comment: [Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` module that contains the `Cert:` drive is not imported automatically into every session. To use the `Cert:` drive, use the `Import-Module` cmdlet to import the module, or run a command that uses the `Cert:` drive, such as a "`Set-Location Cert:`" command.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/6/microsoft.powershell.security/providers/get-childitem-for-certificate)

Comment: @JosefZ: Thanks for that reminder. But "gci -Path Cert:\" failed at one point, and "gci -Path Cert:\LocalMachine" returned certificates. It returned too many certificates, but still returned certificates.

Comment: @harrymc: No errors apart from some "duplicate owners for directory...". I ended yesterday at work with a full backup, in preparation for reinstalling PowerShell.

Comment: I suggest to first fix all disk errors.